# What is the simplest way of getting the solid angle $\Omega_d$ in a space of $d$ dimensions?

Tags: integration, geometry, volume

It is known that the solid angle in a flat space of $d$ dimensions ($d = 2 n$ or $d = 2 n + 1$) is given by these formulae:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\Omega_{2 n} &= \frac{1}{(n - 1)!} \, 2 \pi^n, \qquad
&\Omega_{2 n + 1} &= \frac{2^{2 n} \, n!}{(2 n)!} \, 2 \pi^n.
\end{align}
For examples: $\Omega_1 = 2$, $\Omega_2 = 2 \pi$, $\Omega_3 = 4 \pi$, $\Omega_4 = 2 \pi^2$.  In some papers, it is described as the volume $\mathrm{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d−1})$ of the $d - 1$ unit-sphere (is there a difference?).

Instead of calculating a volume of some object (the unit sphere), suppose an observer is in free fall in a $D$ dimensional spacetime, so space appears to be flat locally (*space* around the observer has $d = D - 1$ dimensions).  The observer wants to calculate the *solid angle* all around himslef, by looking in every orientations.  He should get (1).  What would be the simplest way in deriving these expressions?

Comment: Suggestion: take the [gamma function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Solid_angles_in_arbitrary_dimensions), change it to a recursive form (i.e. $\Omega_d=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{d/2-1}\Omega_{d-1}$, and think about how to prove that recursive form. Then, use either $\Omega_1=2$ or $\Omega_2 = 2\pi$ as the root of the hierarchy.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake, but then what is the relation with the solid angle?  The problem is to find the solid angle in $d$ space, in the simplest way, from *local* considerations only.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic, probably you're right.  But since geometry *is* physics...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_N)$ denote an $N$-tuple of real variables, and 
$$
r\equiv\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_N^2}.
$$
 Define
$$
\Omega(N) = \frac{f(N)}{g(N)}
\tag{1}
$$
with
$$
f(N)\equiv \int d^N x\ \exp(-\mathbf{x}^2)
\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
g(N)\equiv \int_0^\infty dr\ r^{N-1} \exp(-r^2).
\tag{3}
$$
The definition (1) implies that $\Omega(N)$ is the desired quantity (with $N$ denoted $d$ in the OP). The integral $f(N)$ is
$$
f(N)\equiv \left(\int dx\ e^{-x^2}\right)^N = \pi^{N/2}.
\tag{4}
$$
To evaluate the integral $g(N)$, first consider odd $N$. Then $(N-1)/2$ is an integer, so we can use
\begin{align}
g(N)
&= \left(-\frac{d}{da}\right)^{(N-1)/2}
\left.\int_0^\infty dr\  e^{-ar^2}\right|_{a=1}
\\
&=
\left.\left(-\frac{d}{da}\right)^{(N-1)/2}
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4a}}\right|_{a=1}.
\tag{5}
\end{align}
When $N$ is even, the quantity $(N-2)/2$ is an integer, so we can use
\begin{align}
g(N)
&= 
\left.\left(-\frac{d}{da}\right)^{(N-2)/2}
\int_0^\infty dr\  r\,e^{-ar^2}\right|_{a=1}
\\
&= 
\left.\left(-\frac{d}{da}\right)^{(N-2)/2}
\frac{1}{2a}\right|_{a=1}.
\tag{6}
\end{align}

Comment: This is what I believed to be the simplest way.  I think it's the proper answer to my question.